# Is it Possible to Listen Hive Database Data Changes in Flutter without using FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm using Flutter Hive Database for my project with Singleton Pattern.
But I'm stuck in data changes in hive database. Everytimes I added new data to
hive I need to refresh and call again hive database helper class . But I want to listen
data changes in flutter with provider without using hive database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you onlt need to use a  and set a `listenable()` for your specific `Hive` box, an forget about updating state manually, every time your box is updated, it will refresh automatically.

As example, I would say that I have a Hive box called **activities**, I can do like this:

```
ValueListenableBuilder<Box>(
      valueListenable: Hive.box('activities').listenable(),
      builder: (context, box, widget) {
        return Center(
          child: Switch(
            value: box.get('didAgreeOnConditions', defaultValue: false),
            onChanged: (val) {
              box.put('didAgreeOnConditions', val);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

This is a `Switch` widget that will update its state every time I try to switch it, automatically because the listener on the `Hive` Box, notices that something is changed in the box (because I used `box.put('didAgreeOnConditions', val);`)

check out the full `Hive` documentation, [from here](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/hive_in_flutter)

Hope this helps!